# Rotating a UIView inside a UIScrollView, bounds and center point

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a scroll view that contains an UIView subclass that I draw some images into. I would like to be able to rotate the content of the scroll view, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation and keep the functionality of the scroll view (where the inner view is draggable and moveable).

My final goal is to have a map with some dynamically positioned markers, which is scalable and zoomable while rotating with the integrated compass.

(As you may have guessed I'm new to iOS development, so I'm quite lost).

My ViewController containing the ScrollView:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect mapFrame;
    mapFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    mapFrame.size = CGSizeMake(450, 476);
    mapView.frame = mapFrame;

    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 476);
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.7;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
    scrollView.zoomScale = 0.7;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setScrollView:nil];
    [self setMapView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{ 
    return mapView;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{

}
@end
```

My UIView subclass that's embedded in the ScrollView:

```
#import "MapView.h"

@implementation MapView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // do some drawing
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map.jpg"];
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,450,476);
    [myImage drawInRect:rectangle];

    UIImage *testAnimationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_marker.png"];
    UIImageView *testAnimationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testAnimationImage];
    testAnimationView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 34, 34); 
    [self addSubview:testAnimationView];

    // rotate the map - this is where I get stuck
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45 / 180.0 * M_PI); 
    self.transform = transform; 

    // center the rotation point
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.x = 450/2;
    frame.origin.y = 476/2;
    [self setFrame:frame];

}
@end
```

EDIT:

Heres the updated code, after moving the view setup out of drawRect.

ViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapView = [[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 450, 476)];
    [scrollView addSubview:mapView];

    scrollView.delegate = self;

    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 476);
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.7;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
    scrollView.zoomScale = 0.7;

}

-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{ 
    return mapView;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{

}

@end
```

MapView:

```
#import "MapView.h"

@implementation MapView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self layoutView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutView {


    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map.jpg"];
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,450,476);

    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    myImageView.frame = rectangle;

    [self addSubview:myImageView];

    UIImage *testAnimationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_marker.png"];
    UIImageView *testAnimationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testAnimationImage];
    testAnimationView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 34, 34); 
    [self addSubview:testAnimationView];

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 

}

@end
```

Comment: First of all, don't do view layout in `drawRect:`. This method is called every time your view - explicitly or implicitly - says it needs to be updated by calling `setNeedsDisplay`. (Also, don't ever call `drawRect:` yourself.) If you want to display an image, you can much easier do it like this in `initWithFrame:`: `UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map.jpg"]; myImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,450,476); [self addSubview: myImage];`. This way, your code will only be called once. Likewise, don't add the transform in `drawRect:`.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your comment. I've moved all of the layout code out of the drawRect. I had to make an ImageView to put the UIImage in in order to give it a frame. It seems to work fine (it looks the same). However I still don't understand how I apply the rotation to the view properly. Do you have any hints for me to investigate?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, of course I omitted the UIImageView (as an exercise for the reader *ahem*). If you update your question to reflect the new code, I'll have a look at it again :)

Comment: I've updated the question with the updated code (I am also new to StackOverflow so I hope the edit of the original post is OK?).